# replacement for this key word inorder to pass context argument

Tags: java, android, this, android-context

In the program, I am trying to pass the context of the class to the INTENT, but `View.OnClickListener()` is being passed as it is enclosed in the `onClick()` method. What should I write instead of `this`?

```
package com.calender;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class GoTo extends Activity{

Spinner sp;
EditText etyear;
Button submit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.go_to);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spin);
    etyear = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    submit = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bsub);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in = new Intent(this,NextCal.class);
            Bundle bun = new Bundle();
            bun.putString("month", sp.getSelectedItem().toString());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(etyear.getText().toString());
            bun.putInt("year", y);
            in.putExtras(bun);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent in = new Intent(GoTo.this,NextCal.class);

     will solve your problem.
```

Answer (score 1):

you need `GoTo.this` that gives you the context of the activity and not the onClick class